# 3+ egg omelette in a pan

Tags: induction, omelette

I want to make thick omelettes and everywhere online I saw that you start with decent heat and then turn it down all the way after a while, until its thoroughly cooked.

While making 2 eggs, it **just** reaches the edges of my frying pan. So I put 3-4 eggs to make it thicker as it kinda fills up the pan. However after I turn down the heat from 500-600 to 200-300, I notice that after very long time too, it still stays mostly wet on the top. In this time the bottom is overcooked brown. I cannot flip it as it just breaks and leaks from the top.

My Induction temperature ranges from 200-1200, I think it must be Fahrenheit. I don't really have other options since I rent new rooms, and move - a little more than comfortable.

Is it possible to create that golden colored omelette but with a thicker body?

Am I failing because I'm using an Induction stove? Is such a feat possible? If so what must I do to get it done?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a lid?  it might help to keep the heat in so it sets on top

Comment: I think it would help to know what style of omelette you would like to make .. is this a classic French omelette, or more like a Spanish tortilla?

Comment: Megha, I did not try a lid, thank you I will try it.

Comment: Robin, I wanted a French omelette but thicker/with more width. Spanish Tortilla looks a little like a cake, it might also be the right direction I guess. Somehow I wished to fit in around 4 eggs so that I don't have to make two small omelettes and will be done in one shot.

Comment: I've found adding a couple tablespoons of cream to the eggs makes them softer and less prone to breaking when you fold it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm quite new to making omelettes, but when I make a thick/Spanish omelette on the stove (gas) I do a few things that help.  I don't want to turn the grill on just to finish an omelette off, and the handle of my frying pan couldn't really take the grill anyway.

- Push the edges in at first as if cooking a French omelette (to make a thicker, stronger layer quicker).
- Turn the heat down and put a lid on, but not for long.
- Slide it out onto a plate bigger than your frying pan.
- Invert the frying pan over the top of the plate. *Wearing oven gloves* hold them tightly together and flip.
- Continue cooking.

I usually make these because I want them chock-full of onion, potato etc. -- otherwise I make French omelettes, which can be thicker than they traditionally should be (and in that case may be called English).

Alternatively I often precook a filling (onion/peppers/garlic/herb/chillies) and reserve, adding it hot along with some cheese just before folding, while the top is still runny.  It finishes cooking through quite quickly at that point.  Turning is tricky as I tend to overstuff them (it's a favourite quick dinner at the moment,  with freshly-harvested new potatoes so I don't want to be mean with the filling).

Comment: Ohhh that flip is genius! I should be able to slide it after using a lid, I hadn't yet; and it would always have to be folded because it was just kinda raw on top.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how wet the top is, you can also use a silicon scraper to poke little (2 - 3 cm) holes, which the runny top will fill as you tip the pan a bit. You can do this 6 or 8 times without any noticeable marks on the finished omelette (or damage to the structure). You're essentially stretching the omelette in the same pan by creating small voids for the excess egg to fill.

If it's *really* wet, flipping it as Chris H suggests is probably your best bet.